# VSTO Outlook: Modify address book filter programatically with C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I know that the address book is a filtered view of the contacts. I am wondering if I can in somehow intercept the filter applied to the contacts view and change it. Is it possible? if so, how?

**UPDATED 18/10/2022**:

The contacts view I mean that window that is opened when you click on the "Address Book" button from the "Find" category in the top ribbon. See below

[image]

[image]

Comment: "filtered" in what sense? Address book can show other entries (GAL, LDAP, etc.), it is not limited to the entries in one of your Contacts folders.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko what i am trying to do is to add a custom column to the address book grid view. I have heard that the address book is a contact view but with a filter applied. By filter I mean, specify which columns are being visible or not from the contact view.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko See below posts I have found:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/adding-a-column-to-office-365-outlooks-address/908b8024-d347-4871-b66a-15f8434cc23a

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-show-additional-columns-in-my-address/e4aaac5f-04f6-44b7-9515-a0f4549d0039

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/change-columns-in-address-book/a6443c57-cc4f-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

In those three links it is said that the address book is a filtered contact view.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the window where you would like to intercept filters applied?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have updated the post with some screenshots of the Address Book window.

Comment: There is no way to customize the dialog window which comes from the address book provider (on the screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns displayed in the address book view are not configurable. The address book window displays the columns as returned by the underlying address book provider - e.g., CONTAB (for Contacts) or MSEMS for GAL.

Comment: I have updated the post with some screenshots of the Address Book window. Sorry by my ignorance, but what is GAL? I thought that view was obtained by applying a filter (select which columns/fields from contacts folder) over contacts folder, sorry.

Comment: GAL = "Global Address List". That is what you have in your screenshot - the contents come from your Exchange server (AD), not from a Contacts folder in your mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog window is provided by a low-level API on which Outlook is built - Extended MAPI (not Outlook), to be precise - the address book provider. So, the Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for customizing this dialog window simply because it is out of our control (it is not a part of the product).